# Spring boot, multi-tenet, multi-module, @Transactional , parallelStream

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, transactions, multi-module

I am trying to insert some 50k records into db. We have used AbstractRoutingDataSource which resolve Datasource using TenantContext which is a utility class and has a private static final ThreadLocal CURRENT_TENANT = new ThreadLocal<>();

when I am using parallel stream or if I am trying to make the method @Async I am getting the below error

Code:

```
             .parallelStream()
             .forEach(row -> {
                 TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(centerCd);
                 someDao.insert(row);
             });
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target DataSource for lookup key [null]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:305)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target DataSource for lookup key [null]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.determineTargetDataSource(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:207)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:262)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly like you described:  your TenantContext is exactly ThreadLocal and exists in a thread, which is initiated either by `parallelStream()` or `Async` method. (in reality, the call inside of the `Async` or `forEach` method is a `run` from `Runnable`)

The data source is attempted to be injected/resolved at start of the thread: because your transaction have to be started at the thread creation, before your `Runnable` gets into a `run` method. And at this moment of time you haven't yet specified your tenant, call `TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(centerCd)` is performed later in a `run` method implementation.

I would suggest applying such structure to your code:

```
class TenantAwareThread extends Thread {

    public TenantAwareThread(Runnable target, TenantData tenantData) {
        super(target);
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(tenantData);
    }
}

@Autowired
TaskExecutor executor;

void startTask(TenantData tenantData, RowData row) {
    executor.execute(
        new TenantAwareThread(() -> {
            someDao.insert(row);
        },
        tenantData));
}
```

You create a new thread type which is aware of tenant data from the very beginning. And simply wraps your executions into such thread.